# ¿Porque estoy recibiendo un `error de discordancia del tipo MIME` cuando importo el CSS de Bootstrap?

Tags: mysql, nodejs, bootstrap, angular, express

Estoy usando `@angular/cli": "^8.1.2"` y `"bootstrap": "^4.3.1"` y me da error al cargar los CSS de bootstrap que no instale como en un proyecto de desarrollo web con MEAN (con `MySQL`).

Este es el error:

```
El recurso de “http://localhost:4200/frontend/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css” 
fue bloqueado debido a una discordancia del tipo MIME (“text/html”) (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
```

Comment: Agrega un snippet donde muestres como estas cargando el CSS de Bootstrap por favor.

Comment: Lo pongo de dos maneras en mi archivo angula.json y tambien lo he probado en el .html dandole el href= ""   y de ninguna manera me funciona . saludos                                                                             "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.css"
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]

Answer (score 0):

A continuación escribo dos maneras que me han funcionado.

**1. Sin instalar nada, solo utilizando cdn.**

En el archivo *index.html* en la etiqueta *head*

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Antes de terminar el *body*

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**2. Instalando los paquetes**

```
npm install jquery popper.js bootstrap
```

En el archivo *angular.json*

```
"styles": [
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "src/styles.sass"
],
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
]
```

Comment: Gracia Alexander tu respuesta con la instalacion de paquetes me sigue dando el error y debia funcionar pero en mi caso creo q se trata del navegador, pero no le encuentro la solucion para utilizar la forma correcta de cargar los css.Por el momento lo importo directamente del styles.css de angular con @import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"; pero los .js aun no puedo cargarlo ni desde el html ni de angular.json.Y por la CDN no puedo cargarlo pq no tengo internet en todo momento.Saludos

Comment: Que lástima @Leynier, pero a mi siempre me ha funcionado así, deberías hacer una prueba `ng new myApp`, instalar los paquetes de la forma 2 en mi respuesta, después `ng serve -o` y ver si te toma los estilos y los scripts. Si te los toma de esa manera, es porque estas haciendo otras cosas en el servidor y deberías buscar por ese lado, como lo formulan en esta [pregunta](https://www.drupal.org/project/jstools/issues/72561) aunque es en PHP te dará una idea de como reformular tu pregunta o buscar la solución.